# Internal rewrite of domain doesn't work for sub directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a domain, lets say

```
test.example.com
```

The `.HTACCESS` file is at `var/www/html/` and hence `test.example.com` also points to that location.

I would like `test.example.com` to load `/var/www/html/example/test` **internally**.

With the following code

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ example/test%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,QSA,L]
```

The rewrite works for root but when I load `test.example.com/foo` it says 404 when it should instead point to `/var/www/html/example/test/foo` internally and `test.example.com/foo` externally.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your rule with this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example/test%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The problem is that**^$** only matches the root dir and doesnt match when /foobar is requested. I have changed the pattern to **^(.*)$** to allow all uris.

Comment: This externally redirects me to `http://test.example.com/example/test/foo`. I don't want the url in the browser to change.

Comment: No, this doesnt redirect externally. You probably have other rules that are performing this.

Comment: That was my entire .htaccess. This is a fresh apache install.